# Copy an Excel data set multiple times on top of each other

Tags: excel

I have a data set, and I need to copy it x number of times.

I've searched though this forum, and everything I have refers to copying each line x times, like this:

Original:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Copied:

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

etc...

But what I'm looking for is this:

Copied:

```
A
B
C
D
E
A
B
C
D
E
```

etc..

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

PS- each data point is in a separate row, in one column

Answer (score 2):

1. Click and drag selection around rows A B C D E.
2. At the bottom right of the selection box is a little dot.
3. Grab the dot and drag it down and A B C D E will be repeated as
   needed.

Its called the ["fill handle"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-HP001216366.aspx#BMaboutfillhandle).